# Group reversed pair in subsequent rows together using SQL

Tags: sql, reverse

I am working on a dataset of over 500,000 rows with ID for Parent and Child (same family).

However, there are some issues in the dataset where the IDs are reversed (and thus causing loops).

I was able to extract the problematic records (approx. 2000 rows) but I had trouble grouping the reversed ID pairs in **subsequent row** in order to identify the pairs for correction later.

Table 1: Sample problematic data

| YearMonth | ParentID | ChildID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 202101 | 1234 | 5678 |
| 202101 | 9012 | 3456 |
| 202102 | 5678 | 1234 |
| 202102 | 3456 | 9012 |

Table 2: Expected output

| YearMonth | ParentID | ChildID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 202101 | 1234 | 5678 |
| 202102 | 5678 | 1234 |
| 202101 | 9012 | 3456 |
| 202102 | 3456 | 9012 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get your reversed Id paired together you could order by the minimum (or maximum) of the Id columns

```
select *
from t
where exists (
    select * 
    from t t2 where t2.parentid = t.childid and t2.childid = t.parentid
)
order by case when parentId < childId then parentId else ChildId end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.parentid = t.childid and
                    t2.childid = t.parentid
             );
```

Comment: Thank you. I was able to get the output for Table 1 using exists. But I would like the reversed pair to be in a subsequent row order.

Comment: @Cyberwalk . . . I wish people would be clear when they ask questions on what they really want.